# Change fieldset via radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with 2 radio buttons and when either button is toggled it shows or hides a certain fieldset. The issue I have is because the fieldset is just hidden so when the form is submitted it still takes the first fieldsets values.

I have setup a fiddle to show how the form changes the fieldsets http://jsfiddle.net/hhdMq/1/

So when I select "Scale B" although you can change the correct values, when the form is submitted it takes the default values of Scale A.

```
<center>
<input type="radio" name="sellorlet" value="Yes" id="rdYes" checked="yes" />
<label for="rdYes">Scale A</label>
<input type="radio" name="sellorlet" value="No" id="rdNo" />
<label for="rdNo">Scale B</label>
</center>
<fieldset id="sell">
<center>
    <select id="pricemin" name="min">
        <option value="50000">Min Price</option>
        <option value="50000">£50,000</option>
        <option value="100000">£100,000</option>
        <option value="200000">£200,000</option>
        <option value="300000">£300,000</option>
        <option value="400000">£400,000</option>
        <option value="500000">£500,000</option>
        <option value="600000">£600,000</option>
        <option value="700000">£700,000</option>
        <option value="800000">£800,000</option>
        <option value="900000">£900,000</option>
        <option value="1000000">£1,000,000</option>
        <option value="1250000">£1,250,000</option>
        <option value="1500000">£1,500,000</option>
        <option value="1750000">£1,750,000</option>
        <option value="2000000">£2,000,000</option>
        <option value="3000000">£3,000,000</option>
    </select>
    <select id="pricemax" name="max">
        <option value="5000000">Max Price</option>
        <option value="100000">£100,000</option>
        <option value="200000">£200,000</option>
        <option value="300000">£300,000</option>
        <option value="400000">£400,000</option>
        <option value="500000">£500,000</option>
        <option value="600000">£600,000</option>
        <option value="700000">£700,000</option>
        <option value="800000">£800,000</option>
        <option value="900000">£900,000</option>
        <option value="1000000">£1,000,000</option>
        <option value="1250000">£1,250,000</option>
        <option value="1500000">£1,500,000</option>
        <option value="1750000">£1,750,000</option>
        <option value="2000000">£2,000,000</option>
        <option value="3000000">£3,000,000</option>
        <option value="4000000">£4,000,000</option>
        <option value="5000000">£5,000,000</option>
    </select>
</center>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="buy" style="display:none;">
<center>
    <select id="lpricemin" name="min">
        <option value="500">Min Price</option>
        <option value="500">£500</option>
        <option value="600">£600</option>
        <option value="700">£700</option>
        <option value="800">£800</option>
        <option value="900">£900</option>
        <option value="1000">£1000</option>
        <option value="1150">£1150</option>
        <option value="1250">£1250</option>
        <option value="1500">£1500</option>
        <option value="2000">£2000</option>
        <option value="2500">£2500</option>
        <option value="3000">£3000</option>
        <option value="4000">£4000</option>
        <option value="5000">£5000</option>
    </select>
    <select id="lpricemax" name="max">
        <option value="5000">Max Price</option>
        <option value="600">£600</option>
        <option value="700">£700</option>
        <option value="800">£800</option>
        <option value="900">£900</option>
        <option value="1000">£1000</option>
        <option value="1150">£1150</option>
        <option value="1250">£1250</option>
        <option value="1500">£1500</option>
        <option value="2000">£2000</option>
        <option value="2500">£2500</option>
        <option value="3000">£3000</option>
        <option value="4000">£4000</option>
        <option value="5000">£5000</option>
    </select>
</center>
</fieldset>
```

and the jquery used:

```
$("input[name='sellorlet']").change(function () {
$("#sell").toggle(this.value == "Yes");
$("#let").toggle(this.value == "No");

});
```

My question is, how can I completely disable the first fieldset if Scale B is selected and likewise when Scale A is selected it will disable the second fieldset?

Many thanks

Comment: because you have two sets of elements with same name.. rename the names of inputs in the hidden fieldset as a simple hack

Comment: you should move the fieldset outside of you form

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p5Rh6/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When submitting a form, you cannot have two inputs, selects, or textareas with the same name in the same form.  Doing so will cause confusion and probably end up the wrong info being submitted.  There are two ways you can fix this.

**Method 1:**

Change the

`<select id="lpricemin" name="min">`

`<select id="lpricemin" name="lmin">`

to

`<select id="lpricemax" name="max">`

`<select id="lpricemax" name="lmax">` respectively.

This will allow you to handle the data from lmin and lmax and ensure you get the info from the second fieldset.

**Method 2:**

Put the second fieldset in a different form.  Then just change the jQuery to show the forms instead of the fieldsets.

Comment: Yes we could do that but unfortunately the site would require major modification if we were to change the name's of the pricing. I will have a look at changing the forms instead and see what that does.

Comment: @user1857612 I don't know if you designed the site or are just maintaining it, but for future reference, it is considered a bad practice to use the same name value in the same page, similar to the use of identical id's.

Comment: yes it was just temporary thing. I personally don't like working that way but I have now tabbed out the form to get rid of the radio buttons so the whole thing runs as 2 separate forms. Works a lot better also :-)

Answer (score 0):

Changed the radio buttons now to a tabbed design so the form can be separated correctly. If anyone would like to know how the tabs are done they are here http://cssdeck.com/labs/fancy-tabbed-navigation-with-css3-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Method 3 would be to change the switch the content of your select through Javascript rather than toggling through visibility. You can do that through:

```
function setMaxScale()
{
document.getElementById().innerHTML = "<option value="50000">Min Price</option>\
    <option value="50000">£50,000</option>\
    <option value="100000">£100,000</option>\
    <option value="200000">£200,000</option>\
    <option value="300000">£300,000</option>...";
}
```

An other clean solution would be to create your scales dynamically with a loop.